# Make multiple higher ordered functions more consice

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, higher-order-functions

I am trying to make only the first letter of every word Uppercase while removing any spaces at the start and end of the sentence.eg.

> " **a red carpet Is laid beFOre me** " --> "**A Red Carpet Is Laid Before
>   Me**"

I could use regExp but I'm not too familiar with it (suggestions are very welcome). The way I did was by chaining multiple higher-ordered functions, which seem too complex for the given task. I would love any other approach to tackle it.

```js
//this function removes the whitespaces at the extreme ends of passed string

function removeOuterSpace(strArg) {
  return strArg.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, '')
}

// this function takes the actual string and does the rest

function firstUCase(str) {
  var newStr = (removeOuterSpace(str).split(' ')
    .map(function(items) {
      return items[0].toUpperCase() + items.slice(1, items.length)
    })).join(' ')
  return newStr
}

firstUCase(' the quIck brown fox jumps ')
```

Edit: The results came out to be : "The QuIck Brown Fox Jumps"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
function firstUCase(str) {
  var newStr = (str.trim().split(' ')
    .map(function(items) {
      return items[0].toUpperCase() + items.slice(1, items.length).toLowerCase();
    })).join(' ')
  return newStr
}

firstUCase(' the quIck brown fox jumps ') //The Quick Brown Fox Jumps

firstUCase(' a red carpet Is laid beFOre me ') // A Red Carpet Is Laid Before Me
```

Javascript already has a built-in function called [`.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) that (from the docs):

> (...) removes whitespace from both ends of a string. Whitespace in this
>   context is all the whitespace characters (space, tab, no-break space,
>   etc.) and all the line terminator characters (LF, CR, etc.).

Also, you should add `.toLowerCase()` at the end of your sliced part to downcase the rest of the string.

Or, if you want to use **regex**, you can try something like that:

```
function firstUCase(str) {
    return str
        .trim()
        .replace(/\b(\w)(\w*)/g, (word,letter,rest) => letter.toUpperCase() + rest.toLowerCase() )
}

firstUCase(' the quIck brown fox jumps ') //The Quick Brown Fox Jumps

firstUCase(' a red carpet Is laid beFOre me ') // A Red Carpet Is Laid Before Me
```

Above, `.replace` method accepts a function as second parameter (docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)) that can be used to replace the captured groups (first group = first letter, second group = rest of the sentence) with `toUpperCase()` and `toLowerCase()`, respectively. You can play with it here: http://regexr.com/3f4bg

Answer (score 0):

Short solution using `String.prototype.replace` function:

```js
function firstUCase(str) {
  return str.trim().replace(/\b\w+\b/g, function (m) {
    return m[0].toUpperCase() + m.slice(1).toLowerCase();
  });
}
console.log(firstUCase(" a red carpet Is laid beFOre me  "));
```

Comment: can I ask what the w+ does when you already have a 'g' at the end ?

Comment: `\w+` and `/g` modifier are absolutely different things. It's regular expression stuff

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed easier ways. first, `String.prototype.trim()` removes spaces, then as you imagined there is a way to use regex to have a simpler procedure :

```js
function replacer(str){
    return str.toUpperCase();
}
function firstUCase(str) {
  var newStr = str.trim().toLowerCase();//remove spaces and get everything to lower case
  return newStr.replace(/\b\w/g, replacer);
}

console.log(firstUCase(' the quIck brown fox jumps '));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex-based solution:

```js
function replacer(match) {
  return match.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + match.slice(1);
}

function formatString(str) {
  return str
    .trim()
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/\b([a-z])/g, replacer);
}
  
console.log(formatString(" a red carpet Is laid beFOre me "));
```